# XSLT to convert relative to absolute image paths

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having difficulty conceptualizing how to go about converting an image's relative path to an absolute path via xslt.

There currently exists an XML document that has a section `<myHTML>` which holds html encoded text.  This html document may contain `<img>` tags with relative paths - For example: `<img src="myPic.jpg>`

There also exists a xsl that processes that section with a block like this:

```
<div id="bodyText">
  <xsl:value-of select="/abc:myT/abc:myHTML" disable-output-escaping="yes">
</div>
```

I need to prepend an absolute path to the beginning of the image name.  Since the whole html block is being accessed via `value-of select`, I'm not sure how to attack this.

I do believe that I need to use an xsl input parameter in order to pass in the path, but not sure how to access the `<img>` tag inside `<myHTML>`.

And advice would be appreciated.

***Update***

There were some questions as to the format of the XML file and what I meant by "html encoded text".  Please disregard typos, the below chunk is from memory and is representative of the actual xml file. It is meant to illustrate the `HtmlEncode()` data in the `<myHTML>` block.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<?xml-stylesheet ...snipped..>
<myT xmlns="abc">
   <myHTML>
      &lt;html$gt;&lt;head$gt;&lt;title$gt;This is my title&lt;/title$gt;&lt;/head$gt;
      &lt;body$gt;
      &lt;img src="myPic.jpg" /$gt;
      &lt;/body$gt;&lt;/html$gt;
   </myHTML>
</myT>
```

Additionally, as Dimitre pointed out, i'm using .NET and it's XSLT 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is a good reason forcing you to use XLST for this, I'd suggest that it's the wrong tool for the job. Load the XML document into a DOM and XPath to get a node-set containing the relevant myHtml elements. Unescape the HTML and load it into an HTML parser (or if it's XHTML, an XML parser).. again XPath to get the img element, and read/write the href attributes.

In any case - it might help if you could update the question with more details of your problem. Are there constraints forcing you to use XSLT? (In which case, is the HTML escaped in a way that you could reliably regex against?) Is performance an issue? What sort of application is it? Etc. Etc.

Comment: I inferred from the question that the XSLT already exists, so I would assume it's a legacy issue.

Comment: @Dominic, you're obviously an enthusiast for low-level procedural programming. Stick to the old ways yourself if you must, but some of us prefer the declarative approach.

Comment: Not really @MichaelKay, I like XSLT (That might even be partly your fault, considering the hours I've spent with my nose in your book.) To be honest, I was just waiting for Dimitre to jump in with his usual identity tranform based approach, which is correct if the data is XML, but the question says it's "html encoded text", whatever that means. As that's open to interpretation, I've asked for clarification.

Comment: @DominicCronin, whatever "html encoded text" could mean, the OP makes it clear that this is processed with XSLT: "*There also exists a xsl that processes that section*" Based on this I believe that by "html encoded text" the OP means "HTML markup", and because he is able to process it with XSLT, this is most likely XHtml. As for my "usual identity transform", do you mean that using the identity transform is inapropriate? If so, could you, please, give an example? :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I'm not saying you're wrong, but that the question can be taken two ways. (value-of myHTML doesn't process img tags) As you are usually very quick to offer high quality XSLT solutions, I really was expecting the answer you gave. As you have pointed out in several answers I've seen, starting with an identity transform and then "overriding" the interesting bits is a very powerful technique. I was quite happy to assume that not only would you provide this kind of answer, but that you would do it better than I would.

Comment: ... so based on the assumption that the data in myHTML is escaped, and can't be addressed by a select, I've offered an alternative approach. Our answers are therefore not "competing" but rather covering two different scenarios. If the OP clarifies in favour of your scenario, I'll be the first to vote you up.

Comment: @DominicCronin, Both interpretations could be right. I base mine on the OP's comment that he is already processing this with XSLT.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev you already mentioned that. It's a perfectly reasonable interpretation

Comment: Good discussion here, thank you. When I said "html encoded text", I meant it in the sense of HTML markup that has been HTML character encoded, ie- `HtmlEncode()`.  I will update the question with an example for clarity.  From what has been discussed, since the `<img>` tags exist in an `HtmlEncode()`ed string in the XML doc, i'm gathering that XSLT would not be able to access this?

Comment: "Not able to access this" would be putting it too strongly, but we're getting further from XSLT's sweet spot.

Answer (score 0):

Once you use `xsl:value-of`, you're working with a string. So you could use a regex, but that seems shaky. Why not just use a template?

```
<!-- XSL input param -->
<xsl:param name="absolute-path" select="'http://default-path/"></xsl:param>

...

<div id="bodyText">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/abc:myT/abc:myHTML/node()"/>
</div>

...

<xsl:template match="abc:img">
  <img>
     <xsl:attribute name="src">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat($absolute-path,@src)"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@* except @src"/>
  </img>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This makes sense.  Going to try this approach now.

Comment: @xelco52 just fixed a bug in the text() template FYI.

Comment: .NET doesn't seem to like the line: `<xsl:attribute name="src" select="concat($absolute-path,@src)"/>`.  Getting the error: `'select' is an invalid attribute for the 'xsl:attribute' element`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test this. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: The select attribute of xsl:attribute requires XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

**This complete and short and working transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:abc="some:abc" exclude-result-prefixes="abc">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pBase" select="'http://www.copm.com/'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="abc:img[@src]">
  <xsl:element name="img" namespace="some:abc">
   <xsl:attribute name="src">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat($pBase, @src)"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='src')]|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document:**

```
<myT xmlns="some:abc">
    <myHTML>
        <img src="myPic.jpg"/>
    </myHTML>
</myT>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (any `src` attribute of an `img` element is converted to absolute, using the provided as parameter base):

```
<myT xmlns="some:abc">
   <myHTML>
      <img src="http://www.copm.com/myPic.jpg"/>
   </myHTML>
</myT>
```

**Update**:

As noted by Michael Kay, in XSLT 2.0 and later one should use the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`resolve-uri()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-resolve-uri)**.

However, from comments of the OP it has become clear that he is using a .NET XSLT processor, which means an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: But note that in XSLT 2.0, the resolve-uri() function gives you a more "accurate" way of forming an absolute URI than concat(). Doing it yourself with concat() in this way will fail for example if the input is already an absolute URI, and will give messy results for example if the relative URI starts with "../".

Comment: @MichaelKay, Absolutely correct. I assumed that the OP needs an XSLT 1.0 solution. In XSLT 2.0 one should definitely use resolve-uri().

Comment: Thank you Dimitre.  I updated the question to clarify the xml format.

Comment: @xelco52, This cannot be done in pure XSLT 1.0 (unless you implement an XML parser entirely in XSLT 1.0) without an extension function. Are you interested in a solution with an extension function?